# Resolving two types of YouTube channel URLs in API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

I'm taking a youtube url as user input. 
The logic I have is as follows:
if(URL === link_to_video) then get video
else if( URL == link_to_channel) then get all_videos_of_channel.

I am doing this via JavaScript and using the YouTube API v3.

The problem is, it seems youtube has two types of URLs to youtube channels.

- /channel/, eg:
  www.youtube.com/channel/UCaHNFIob5Ixv74f5on3lvIw
- /user/,
  eg: www.youtube.com/user/CalvinHarrisVEVO

both the above links will take you to the same channel, but my current uploader code supports only /user/CalvinHarrisVEVO.

is there any way to make both the URLs behave similarly in terms of obtaining the channel videos?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to parse the url and then apply this logic:

```
if there is `channel` in the url link
    call the APIv3 with the **id** of the channel
    Ressource : youtube.channels.list
else if there is 'user'
    call the APIv3 with the **forUsername** of the channel
    Ressource : youtube.channels.list
```

Check : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list

Comment: thanks! I believe I'll have to separate the two cases